# Can I specify a custom .js script in Chrome similar to custom CSS file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, javascript

Chrome used to allow you to have your own user-defined CSS file.  I think that ended as of Chrome 34.  However there is an extension to allow you to have a user-defined CSS file.

Is there any way or extension to similarly specify a custom `.js` script or file?

Comment: According to this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija), it should do that.

Comment: You can use this extention  as well :https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-style-script/ecjfaoeopefafjpdgnfcjnhinpbldjij?hl=en